# What's the purpose of "Just as" here?

Tags: phrase-usage

Vronsky took a smoking cigar from Anna:

> Anna: I'll try another one sometime.
>
> Vronsky: When? Where?
>
> Anna: **Just as** I was thinking your manners had improved since Moscow.
> You behaved badly.

What's the purpose of "Just as" here?

Comment: That would normally be *Vronsky took a **lit** cigar from Anna*, not ***smoking***. When Anna says ***just as** [something was happening, something **else** happened **immediately afterwards**]*. This particular usage doesn't normally imply that the first thing *causes* the second thing - or at least, that implication isn't very strong. Compare with ***Speak of the devil** [and he will appear]*. Basically, Anna means it's particularly "poignant / irritating / unusual" that Vromsky should behave badly immediately after she's just started to have a better opinion of him.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meaning of **just as** here is "exactly at the same time".  I would say [the definition of **just** is adverb #1a: "exactly or precisely"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/just) and [the definition of **as** is conjunction #5: "while or when"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/as)

To put it in other words, Anna is saying, "I had started to think your manners had improved, and exactly when I started to think that, you proved me wrong."